# Annotation for naming classes to be read by reflection

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

My application allows developers to create some plugins. Сompliance with the requirements determined by base abstract class. Each plugin must have a name. I want to solve this problem by using annotations. So, I defined my own annotation Name as follows:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Name {
public String value();
}
```

I put this annotaion and base abstract class CommonPlugin into separate module and build it as JAR-file to share with developers.

Then I import package and put this annotation before the defenition of me test plugin as follows:

```
@Name("Test plugin")
public class TestPlugin extends CommonPlugin {
```

Then I reflect all given plugins through `URLClassLoader` and can't find necessary annotation at TestPlugin class. But if I define Name annotation into the same package the TestPlugin class is, I can find it. It should be so or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That doesn't sound like it should be this way. Are your packages and imports set up in such a fashion that the unqialified name `Name` refers to the same qualified name in all of your sources? You can use `javap` to see what annotations are stored in a class, to see whether the problem lies with the creation or the loading of that `TestPlugin` class.

Comment: Yes, i've changed the name of annotation to PluginName and problem was solved. Probably, the name 'Name' wasn't the best choise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my coment into an answer so it can be accepted.*

Make sure that the unqualified name `Name` refers to the same qualified name in all of your source files. In sources from different packages than the one containing the annotation, there should be a non-wildcard import for `Name`, and there should be no class with that name in that other package itself.